# Privacy of in-app purchases: how much user data does the app developer get?

Tags: privacy, in-app-purchase

When a you do an in-app purchase like buying a feature or subscription the the app and the developer is getting data on your purchase.

I searched a bit the Google documentation but I wasn't able to determine what user-data from the used Google-account used by the purchase is made accessible to the app and it's developer.

Technically it should be possible to implement this whole process in a way that the app and it's developer does not get access to any user-related data like Google account e-mail, user name or similar data. The app and it's developer should only get the data what item/subscription you have bought and may be a random user-id only Google can relate to your account.

Is there any official documentation available about the privacy of in-app purchases like what user-related data is shared with the app and it's developer?

Comment: I'm no developer, and have not used Google Play's services since ages. That said, it appears that during billing developer gets obfuscated [account and profile id](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/AccountIdentifiers). But than, there is this API which pretty much leaks many sensitive info about the user. See https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions

Does this make any sense? I can't piece the two things together.

Comment: There's a self-deleted Q&A posted in 2018 about a similar topic: [What personal information is shared from the Play Store to an Android Developer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200894/44325)

Comment: @Firelord The first link was really valuable. If I understand it correctly the app and it's developer don't get any information about your Google account at all. It works the other way, the app provides an (obfuscated) account/profile id. This means if the app developers was careless Google may get the account name or email of the app account  but not the other way around.

Comment: The second link seems to be related to a more general API, mainly designed for web services. This API provides detailed user information (name, e-mail, ...) to the developer using this API. Luckily all those privacy related fields are marked according to the description as "Subscribe with Google" only. Not sure if this service is available outside of the US (never heard of it). What I read it seems to be dedicated to website paywalls, especially for newspapers and similar sites who want to collect micro-payment for access e.g. to an article.